# How to iterate through a JSONObject(complex) and select key-value pair and insert it to a Map

Tags: java, json

I want to write a code that can iterate the given JSONObject and would select only the key-value pair and insert it to a map.
For instance, this is my JOSNObject ->

> {
> "_id": {
> "docId": "123456"
> },
> "meta": {
> "tId": "8267"
> },
> "body": {
> "startDate": {
> "sdate": "2020-01-01T06:00:00Z"
> },
> "endDate": {
> "edate": "2021-06-30T05:00:00Z"
> }
> }
> }

I want to have only the actual/useful key-value pair in a map, like

> "docId"="123456",  "tId"="8267", "sdate"="2020-01-01T06:00:00Z" , "edate"="2021-06-30T05:00:00Z"

Any help would be much appreciated!

Just to make things much clear I'm looking for a solution or a way where I can get the value of JSONObject without specifying the key name explicitly.

Comment: Firstly, which JSON library are you using? There are a few such libraries which define a class called JSONObject but they're defined differently from each other despite having the same name. Secondly, how many levels of depth do you want to go down? Your example shows 1 and 2 levels of depth (i.e. the key "docId" is inside "_id" so it's 1 level of depth, but "sdate" is inside "startDate" which is inside "body", so that's 2 levels of depth).

Comment: I'm using org.json.JSONObject as the library.
Speaking about the depth level,  in my case, it'll be 1 as well as 2. so I can expect a max 2 levels of depth.

Comment: Try using [optJSONObject](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONObject-java.lang.String-) to check if you need to recurse; otherwise, the value is a simple object which you can put straight into the map. Have a go and if you get stuck, add your code to the question and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: @k314159 I did a quick search on optJSONObject but was not able to find a good solution that can help me, if possible could you please paste an example that I can start with?

Comment: I originally wrote an example using `optJSONObject` (the first version of my answer) but then replaced it a simple `.get()` and checking if the returned object is another JSONObject - this second version turned out to be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive solution:

```
public static Map<String, Object> leafEntries(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
        Object nestedObject = jsonObject.get(key);
        if (nestedObject instanceof JSONObject)
            result.putAll(leafEntries((JSONObject) nestedObject));
        else
            result.put(key, nestedObject);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And here's a unit test (which it passes):

```
@Test
void test() {
    var jsonObject = new JSONObject("""
            {
                "_id": { "docId": "123456" },
                "meta": { "tId": "8267" },
                "body": {
                    "startDate": { "sdate": "2020-01-01T06:00:00Z" },
                    "endDate": { "edate": "2021-06-30T05:00:00Z" }
                }
            }""");
    assertThat(leafEntries(jsonObject)).containsOnly(
            entry("docId", "123456"),
            entry("tId", "8267"),
            entry("sdate", "2020-01-01T06:00:00Z"),
            entry("edate", "2021-06-30T05:00:00Z"));
}
```

(The unit test uses AssertJ library and Java 16 syntax, but the production function is compatible with Java 8 upwards.)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, using the map name call
mapName.values()
this will return a list of values to you
then you can iterate on that list
and insert the values in the map.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Yes it would be better if you add a demo code to understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for something like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject ("{\"hi\":\"hello\"}");
for (Iterator i = json.keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext ();) {
    String key = (String) i.next ();
    Object val = json.get(key);
    // Write logic to select the fields you want
    // e.g. val instanceof String (for key with string value)
    System.out.println (val);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @NasirRabbani, but I'm looking for something where I don't have to specify the keys and get the values, instead I'm looking for something that while iterating I could skip the those keys which are not needed and could use only their values. For instance -
This is my actual JSONObject -
{ "_id": { "docId": "123456" }, "meta": { "tId": "8267" } }
I would like to skip the key "_id" and "meta" and would like to get only their values.